# Battery or power adapter problem?

Tags: battery, power, charging

I have a problem charging my battery.

When I plug my power adapter into my MacBook Pro, the power adapter's light turns green (it doesn't change to orange) and my monitor light turns on (which means the laptop is getting power from the adapter)—but the battery wouldn't charge.

[image]

However, when I use my friend's power adapter, my battery does charge.

Is there a problem with my power adapter or something else?

Comment: It’s either your MagSafe or your cord, get a new adapter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> PS: when I use my friend's magsafe it
>   charges my MacBook Pro.

Sorry if this is too obvious, but if your friend's magsafe charger indeed charges the battery without any problems, then it certainly seems like the **problem is in your charger**. (Somewhere in it; the cord, magsafe adapter, or some other part.)

Comment: If it's the cord, [this](http://www.instructables.com/id/MacBook-Mag-Safe-Charger-Budget-Repair-Disas/) might be of help. Proceed with your own risk :)

Comment: dude I know My sentences was so obvious, but if my charger was damaged then why when plug it in the monitor light turn on?

Comment: Hmm, if the laptop receives power, but doesn't charge the batteries, my best guess is that the charger is only *partially* damaged. :-) By the way: [something possibly related](http://superuser.com/questions/111705/why-does-my-magsafe-power-connector-only-work-one-way-round) (does it work if you insert the adapter the other way round?).

Comment: no it's not work for me :(

Comment: Finally I buy a new Magsafe Adapter :(